# Disable anchor menu click on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a nested list as a menu with sub menu items. I used to do it where if you hovered over main menu item, the sub menu items would appear by changing the display from none to block.
I decided to make the sub menus looks as if they were dropping down and used CSS transitions.

The problem I have is that in the first approach if you touched a main menu item on an iPad the sub menu would display and you would touch it again to follow the link.
With the new approach it follows the link on the iPad and you don't get to see the sub menu.

The menus that have nothing below them (sub menu items and main menu items with no sub menu items) have one class while the main menu items with a sub menu below them have a different class.

Is there any way I can set it so that hovering over the menu would show the sub menu items on a desktop and clicking would follow the link while touching a main menu item on an iPad would follow the link if there was no sub menu items but follow the link on a second touch and show the sub menu on the first touch when there is a sub menu?

```
    <div id="menu">
    <div class="mainmenu">
         <ul>
            <li class='menu_child'>
                <a href=''>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class='menu_child'>
                <a href=''>Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class='menu_parent'>
                <a href=''>Contact Us</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href='' >Find Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href='' >About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href='' >Meet the Team</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='menu_parent'>
            <a href=''  >Adventure</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href='' >Adventurer Grandmaster</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='menu_child'>
            <a href='' >Guilds</a>
        </li>
        <li class='menu_parent'>
            <a href='' >Trade</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href='' >Moonsea</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href='' >Hillsfar</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href='' >Femphrey</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href='' >Anvil</a>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

First approach

```
    .mainmenu ul ul{
float: left;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
width: 274px;
z-index: 1001;
display: none;
}

.mainmenu ul li:hover ul, .mainmenu li.over ul {
display: block;
}
```

Second approach

```
.mainmenu ul ul{
float: left;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
width: 274px;
z-index: 1001;
    height: auto;
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
}

.mainmenu ul li:hover ul, .mainmenu li.over ul{
max-height: 999px;
-webkit-transition-duration:1s;
    -moz-transition-duration:1s;
    -o-transition-duration:1s;
    -ms-transition-duration:1s;
    transition-duration:1s;
}
```

I've adding focus and active pseudo-classes to the hover bit.

I'm willing to use JavaScript but I'd rather do it with CSS, preferably without changing the HTML. I'm willing to use PHP as a last resort.

Comment: This has nothing to do with php so please remove that as a tag

Answer (score 4):

**http://jsbin.com/cilapi/2/**

The trick is to **prevent a click** on any `.menu_parent` element's first inner `a` anchor using CSS `pointer-events: none;` **on mobile**

```
@media (max-width: 768px)  { /* Small devices */

  li.menu_parent > a {    // If LI element is parent to a submenu
    pointer-events: none; // prevent it's immediate A child to follow HREF
    cursor: default;     
  }

}
```

`:hover` will still work as usual on larger screens and a click will follow a link.
On smaller `@media` devices - any element that is `.menu_parent` parent will have clicks disabled on it's `>` immediate `a` child, allowing the sub menu to open (instead of triggering the HREF follow)

Comment: What happens on a mobile phone if I want to follow the menu parent's link. Will it be disabled or will a second touch allow it?

Comment: @richard Yes. It will keep being disabled. Heres where JS could come in place or rather jQuery. If the LI is opened change the CSS of the inner A to default pointer events. Reset to none after its closed.

Comment: That seems to make sense. It is possible with JS or doesn't it have to be jQuery becuase I'm not very familar with jQuery and can't seem to make sense of it? Is the script a simple one?

Comment: @RichardYoung ofc it's possible in pure JS (using jQuery is just simpler) I don't know how much JS you know and if I have the time right now  to write it for you :(