# Remove href from link but need the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know how to call it because I am amateur.
I have a dropdown like this:

```js
    $('#q1').on('click', function(evt) {
        //evt.preventDefault();
        var drop = $('#q2');
        if ( drop.hasClass('show')) {
            drop.removeClass('show');
            drop.removeAttr()
        } else {
            drop.dropdown('toggle');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="q1">Dog</a>
    <div id="q2">
        <a href="#">Dog 1</a>
        <a href="#">Dog 2</a>
        <a href="#">Dog 3</a>
    </div>
```

My question is:
How to avoid the href on id="q1" on mobiles in order to use only the dropdown.
On desktop I want to keep the href on id="q1"

So I want on desktop to have my dropdown on mouse hover, and on mobile by tapping on q1, but no href need, because I can't use dropdown

Comment: You have to detect if the user use a mobile device and use a function like this: $('a').on('click',function(e){ e.preventDefault; }); If you are new to programming you can read the documentation about Jquery and Html. P.S. for the dropdown its better to use <select>

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33292421/4875631 (Just need to reverse the condition)

Comment: I know I can read the documentation, and I've read it but I don't know how to do it. I've tried but I miss something

Comment: Explain your question better, tell the community what you have tried. That way your question will get answered.
If you found the answer - post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Use .preventDefault() [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
together with this IF

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

```js
 if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $('#q1').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.google.com" id="q1">Google</a>
```

Comment: If I use this preventdefault, the bootstrap "drop.dropdown('toggle');" doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

Since you have jQuery tagged, you could use that.

```
<script>
    if ($(window).width() < 700) {
        $("#q1").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
    } else {
        $("#q1"). removeAttr("href");
    }
</script>
```

You could change the 700 to whatever width is required.